# time performance enhancment in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have different text files and different outputs from different sources. I need to have the output on different lines on a text document file. The code is as follows

```
for (( x = 1 ; x < 1000 ; x++ )) do

difference=$((file1 - file2))
echo $(tshark -r 1.pcap -c 1 -t ad | \
        awk -F" " '{print $2,$3}')  $difference \
        $(awk 'FNR == "'$z'" {print}' 1.txt) >> ~/Desktop/information.txt
done
```

It works fine, but it takes a long time. I beleive it is because the script is accessing the text document many times in a loop. Any idea how to use other approaches to enhance the speed performance?

Thanks

Comment: What does it _do_? What is `file1` or `file2`? What is the awk for? Is there a sample of `pcap` file contents? Because, yeah, there is loads of room for improvement, but this is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Actually interesting looking code, but how are we supposed to guess what's happening and how we can help make it better!? :-) ... Editted into your question using the `{}` format tool at the top left of the input box ... 1 Sample inputs, 2 required output, 3 current output, 4 discussion of problems with current output, 5 code (you've got that). .... Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply :). I am asking as a general question. So the input or output dont matter. The idea is I need to write to a text file at multiple times from different sources, each on a different line.

Comment: It is very unclear to me why you loop over $x which you do not seem to use in the rest of your code. Also file1 and file2 seem not to change so why can they the difference not be computed outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with taking the redirection out of the loop:

```
for (( x = 1 ; x < 1000 ; x++ )) do
  difference=$((file1 - file2))
  echo $(tshark -r 1.pcap -c 1 -t ad | \
        awk -F" " '{print $2,$3}')  $difference \
        $(awk 'FNR == "'$z'" {print}' 1.txt)
done >> ~/Desktop/information.txt
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. It provided the same result