# connections duration calculation process time

Tags: bash, wireshark, tshark

I am using the following code in bash linux to extract time duration for each connection

```
for a in folder/*.pcap 
do

difference=$(echo $(tshark -r $a  -T fields -e frame.time_epoch | tail -n 1) - $(tshark -r $a -T fields -e frame.time_epoch | head -n 1) | bc)

echo $difference

done
```

However, the process time is very high (1 minute for 100 pcaps). Any ideas how to improve process time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [time performance enhancment in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666043/time-performance-enhancment-in-bash-script)

Comment: Hi shelter. This is another question in term of calculating connection duration

Comment: Check out [Bro](http://www.bro.org), which computes the connection duration [and other statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10066658/1170277) out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
myfun() {
  a=$1
  difference=$(echo $(tshark -r $a  -T fields -e frame.time_epoch | tail -n 1) - $(tshark -r $a -T fields -e frame.time_epoch | head -n 1) | bc)
  echo $difference
}
export -f myfun
parallel myfun ::: folder/*.pcap
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: http://pi.dk/1

10 seconds installation:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```